# Windows & Mac XML library for delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, xml-parsing, cross-platform, delphi-xe2

What is the best (easy to use, performances) library to manage XML on Delphi XE2. Windows and Mac targets in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [OmniXML](http://code.google.com/p/omnixml/), it is:

1. 100% written in delphi
2. Has no outer dependencies
3. Works on XE2, did not test it on OSX

On top of OmniXML you can use [SimpleStorage](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplestorage/) to give you more power and simplicity managing the XML.

Comment: There is also 'OmniXML by Kluug.net'. It is tested on Win32 / Win64 and MacOSX. See http://www.kluug.net/omnixml.php

Answer (score 4):

I usually go for the NativeXML library, it's an XML library completely written in Delphi code and it's free. I'm not sure if the latest version offers compatibility with the Firemonkey platform, but with a few changes to unit names I tested it successfully back when Delphi XE2 was first released.

You can find the component here: http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html
In case the latest version isn't compatible with XE2 yet, there's a topic on the forums about how to make it compatible: http://www.simdesign.nl/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2110

Comment: I'm using it fine in FireMonkey, on Windows and iOS

Answer (score 3):

Andreano Lanusse has a nice [blog post](http://www.andreanolanusse.com/en/creating-xml-files-with-delphi-and-firemonkey-on-mac/) on using XML on Mac. It turns out that:

> When you drop a TXMLDocument component on your design the default DOMVendor MSXML, you have to change to ADOM XML v4 to support cross-platform.

Comment: @philnext: Andreano is talking in this article about using XML on Windows and Mac. At the end he shows an example how to manipulate XML files on Mac using standard component TXMLDocument. Delphi XE2 offers XML support on Windows and Mac out-of-the-box as Andreano shows. If future versions of Delphi support other platforms, it is expected that TXMLDocument support these other platforms as well.