# Delphi4 XE / iOS / read XML file /

Tags: ios, xml, delphi

Am I correct in that Delphi 4 XE Pro does not supply any native way of reading XML documents? (TXMLDocument is Windows only) I have pondered about using TClientDataSet, but I am not sure if that is the right way to go.

Here is an example of what I want:
Readonly XML file that defines a list of contacts. In the XML file, it also contains e.g. file path to photo of contact.

Ideally I then want to show the data in e.g. a TListBox (which might mean I need to write my own logic for loading images in/out of memory.)

Comment: This might be [`the answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17361981/960757).

Comment: I am still hoping they have a native solution for Delphi/mobile development. Otherwise I will of course need to look into 3rd party solutions :(

Comment: Libxml2 libraries are 100% native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If validation is not required (as in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17361981/960757) above), try

[NativeXml](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html) 
or
[OmniXML](http://code.google.com/p/omnixml/)

Both are free open source libraries for Delphi, however I have not checked if they can be used on other platforms.

Update: see http://www.kluug.net/omnixml.php and [Windows & Mac XML library for delphi XE2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861634/windows-mac-xml-library-for-delphi-xe2)

Comment: You lead me on right path. From http://www.andreanolanusse.com/en/creating-xml-files-with-delphi-and-firemonkey-on-mac/
"When you drop a TXMLDocument component on your design the default DOMVendor MSXML, you have to change to ADOM XML v4 to support cross-platform."